# Best alternative to re.findall that can utilize a list rather than regex

Tags: python, sql

I’m somewhat new to coding, so I apologize in advance if the answer is obvious here.

I’m looking for a Python or SQL solution that would identify all keywords from a given list of over 170k strings within individual fields in a table. 
Utilizing `re.findall` is not necessary, but is the closest I’m aware of to the kind of solution I’m seeking.

For example, if my list of keywords included: 
`bite`, `ankles`, `flesh`, `wound` and the target column in my table contained the following fields sequentially:

> I’ll bite your ankles.
>
> Only a flesh wound.
>
> Flesh ankles bite only.

I would like a new column created in the table that contains the following fields in sequential order:

> bite ankles
>
> flesh wound
>
> flesh ankles bite

To further complicate this problem I have access to limited libraries in the environment I’m forced to use so the more basic the better. Thank you in advance for any assistance with providing a shell I could use to plug my table and list into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string

key_list = ["bite", "ankles", "flesh", "wound"]
input_list = ["I'll bite your ankles", "Only a flesh wound.", "Flesh ankles bite only."]
output_list = []

up_key_list = [i.lower() for i in key_list]

for inp in input_list:
   output_list.append(" ".join([i for i in string.split(inp, " ")  if string.lower(i) in up_key_list]))

print (output_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, both solutions worked but noticed that if punctuation is adjacent to a keyword it will not be returned in the results. Is there a way to wildcard adjacent characters so to speak or do I need to strip out punctuation from the strings? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

For Python, you can start with something like this:

```
>>> # make a set of the keywords
... keywords = {"bite", "ankles", "flesh", "wound"}
>>> # get the input as list of strings
... strings = ["I’ll bite your ankles", "Only a flesh wound", "Flesh ankles bite only"]
>>> [" ".join(filter(lambda x: x.lower() in keywords, s.split(" "))) for s in strings]
['bite ankles', 'flesh wound', 'Flesh ankles bite']
```

Comment: Note: Iterating over sets in python tends to be slower than iterating over lists

Comment: But containment test (which is used here) is O(1) instead of O(n), which means that it's more efficient for large lists of keywords.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, was too tired when I wrote this. I'll still leave the comment, but in this program everything was done right +1